# When are foreign keys generated for related entities

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

In using the Entity Framework (v6.1) I am wondering when the foreign key relationship is set between  parent/child entities.

Assume that I have an Owner entity that represents a pet Owner . I also have a Pet entity that represents a pet that has an Owner. When creating a new Owner I want to create one or many Pet entities that are owned by the Owner entity.

```
Owner newOwner = New Owner();
newOwner.LastName = "John";
newOwner.FirstName = "Doe";

Pet newPet1 = new Pet();
newPet1.Type = "Cat":
newPet1.Name = "Whiskers";

Pet newPet2 = new Pet();
newPet2 .Type = "Dog":
newPet2 .Name = "Fido";

// Add pets to Owner
newOwner.Add(newPet1);
newOwner.Add(newPet2);

// Add Owner to collection
Owners.Add(newOwner);
```

1. Does a foreign key (the OwnerId) get automatically populated for the Pet entities? Assume that the Owner entity has a primary key in entity model and the Pet entity has the OwnerId as a foreign key.
2. How could one get back the primary keys generated for each entity?
3. Are the keys only generated after .SaveChanges() is called?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the entities with foreign keys first
then you can create and save entities

ex

First entity 'district' which will have multiple moh_areas

```
    public class District
    {
        public District()
        {
           List<MOH_area>  MOH_areasList = new List<MOH_area>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int dist_id { get; set; }
        public string dist_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MOH_area> MOH_areas { get; set; }
    }

Next entity

    public class MOH_area
    {
        public MOH_area() { }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? moh_id { get; set; }
        public string moh_name { get; set; }

        public int dist_id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("dist_id")]
        public virtual District District { get; set; }
    }

Now you can create and insert objects to db

    district dd= new destrict();
    dd.dist_name="abcdef";
    db.district.Add(dd);
    db.SaveChanges();

    MOH_area mo=new MOH_area();    // create and add many child elements
    mo.moh_name="my moh";
    mo.dist_id=dd.dist_id;  //  it has the id auto filled after the db insert
    db.MOH_area.add(mo);
    db.savechanges();

    MOH_area mo2=new MOH_area();    // create and add many child elements // no 2
    mo2.moh_name="my 2nd moh";
    mo2.dist_id=dd.dist_id;  //  it has the id auto filled after the db insert
    db.MOH_area.add(mo2);
    db.savechanges();
```